# Fibration induced by an almost complex structure

Tags: fibration, almost-complex

Let $E \rightarrow M$ be a plane bundle endowed with an almost complex structure $J.$ $J$ induces a natural positive definite inner product in the associated bundle $$End(E)\rightarrow M,$$ denoted by $<,>.$ Now consider the set $$P=\{(p,A)| \,\ p \in M, \,\ A \in End(E_p), \,\ <A,J>=0, \,\ <A,id>=0, <A,A>=1 \}$$

$P$ is a circle fibration above $M.$ Are there any conditions on $J$ that will guarantee $P$ is trivial?

Comment: Could you explain how you get a positive definite inner product on $\operatorname{End}(E)$ from $J$?

Comment: @Michael Take $A,B \in End(E_p)$ and then chose a frame  $e_1,e_2$ in $E_p$ such that $$J(e_1)=-e_2 ,\,\ J(e_2)=e_1.$$ This can always be done for an almost complex structure( I believe the name for such a frame is complex frame?). With respect to this frame the matrix of the endomrphism $A$ is $ a_{ij}$ and the matrix of $B$ is $b_{ij}$. Then define $$ <A,B>=\sum_{ij} a_{ij}b_{ij}.$$ The product defined this way is independent of the choice of the complex frame(I hope I use the right term).